# Phonegap: access JavaScript file in "plugins" folder

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

### Problem:

I am using Phonegap and installed a plugin for native page transitions 
(Tutorial: https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-native-transitions)

My plugin directory changed after a successfull installation to:

```
plugins
    cordova-plugin-native-transitions
        src
        www
            nativetransitions.js
        package.json
        plugin.xml
        README.md
    fetch.json
```

### Question:

If I try to use the plugin, it wont work
(Uncaught ReferenceError: nativetransitions is not defined)

But I can't access it directly, any suggestions how I can access the JavaScript file in the plugins directory?

### Edit:

Do I have to copy-paste the file from the www directory to the main www directory? Tried that but still not working...

### Edit 2:

Moved it to the main www folder and included it in my HTML, but when I try to call it, i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativepagetransitions' of undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried loading nativetransitions.js in your html?

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin. You don't have to link the plugin .js file, that's done automatically for you. But you have to link the cordova.js, did you link it?

Comment: Oh okay, didn't knew it will be linked automatically. I did include the cordova.js. I will reinstall it, thanks for your comment.